# Why Twig and not Blade in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, theming

I was lately asked the question why Drupal 8 uses [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) as templating engine and not [Blade](http://daylerees.com/codebright/blade), which is used in Laravel.

I couldn't answer the question.

But is there a specific reason why Drupal 8 uses Twig and not Blade? Maybe because it's a Symfony component and they already use lots of Symfony components?

Comment: -1 on the flamebait "Blade was better then Twig".

Comment: Where's the source for Blade? I can't find it.

Comment: Along with whole Laravel thing, Blade has no documentation. This Laravel maybe easy to learn but without a good documentation it is no worth for me

Comment: Looking at http://daylerees.com/codebright/blade, I can find multiple reasons why Twig is IMHO better for Drupal. a) It still executes PHP, so people can still do whatever they want  in templates. b) escaping needs to be specified explicitly (three { instead of two). No way you would get that past @chx ;) c) I could be wrong, but twig seems to offer more flexibility how {{ something }} is turned into actual HTML. Did not actually try it out, so some parts of this could be wrong.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if we need to close this question, maybe change the wording a bit? It specifically asks why Drupal chose Twig instead of Blade, not which of those is better. and I think that can be answered, and the answer from @Letharion seems pretty good on that (Blade not really existing by the time the work on twig integration started).

Comment: Why so many downvotes? ...

Comment: @nielsv I explained my down vote in the first comment above, I can't speak of the others of course.

Comment: Thinking more about it, I think the fundamental problem here, is that the question doesn't suggest any reason why Drupal _would_ use Blade. As it stands, we could duplicate the question once for every single template system there is. It would have been different, and a better question, I think, had it contained "In Drupal, doing X is often a real difficulty. Blade solves that. Why didn't D8 go with Blade instead of Twig?". For example.

Comment: Why is Drupal 8 using Twig? Because I [said so](https://www.drupal.org/node/1499460) and got everyone to agree and a legion of people to help.

Comment: I still prefer Blade, but I'm a WordPress/Laravel dev, so my opinion's mute ;)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell, there's *very* little information about blade on the internet. It doesn't even appear to be available as a standalone library. That seems like it would be reason enough.

Twig development [originally](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/twig/commit/76553dd93bf091f2997821301afa2d6e884a7681) started in 2008. It had it's [first release in 2009](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php).

The simple fact that I can't even find the same information about Blade suggests it is significantly less mature. (Which doesn't mean it's worse in any way)

The [oldest commit](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/abc1fad6) I *can* find, is from September 2011.

The [official](https://www.drupal.org/node/1696786) attempt to merge in Twig was started in July 2012.

At that point in time, Blade was, as far as I can tell, not even a year old, and consisted of a whooping total of [453 lines of code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/0a85a54c2fc022b5ed63389fa282d26220c551ac/laravel/blade.php), where as Twig had it's first *release*, a little less than 3 years earlier.

And keep in mind that the unofficial discussions to integrate Twig will have started far earlier.